# Elegant way to avoid multiple template instantiatons of function that doesn't depend on templated type

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, c++11

I have a basic class looking something like this:

```
template <typename TCode, TCode SuccessVal>
class Error
{
public:
    typedef TCode code_t;

    Error(TCode code, char const *descr="Unknown Error."):
        code(code), descr(descr)
    {

    }

    ...

    char const *description() const
    {
        return descr;
    }

    ...

private:
    TCode code;
    char const *descr;
};
```

All it does is encapsulate some kind of error code enum class so that it provides a bit more context for logging.

Now say I have a function `panic`:

```
template <typename TCode, TCode SuccessVal>
void panic(Error<TCode, SuccessVal> const &e)
{
    puts("Panic!");
    printf("Unrecoverable error: %s", e.description());
    abort();
}
```

Compiling with -fdump-tree-original shows that in my case this results in a couple of distinct functions, with the exact same code. This is what you would expect, but probably not what you would desire.

An obvious route would be a base class that just had the message and a constructor taking the message, but I find that rather unattractive.

We don't ever use the error code itself so nothing we do depends on T. How can I avoid a ton of template instantiations that compile to basically the same code?

Another desirable feature would be to make sure that whatever type TCode is, it is coercible to an integer type.

Comment: In Visual Studio and other toolchains, the linker detects these and merges them.

Comment: @MooingDuck: That's a good point!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An obvious factorization of this code would be this:

```
[[noreturn]] void panic_with_message(char const * msg)
{
    std::printf("Panic!\nUnrecoverable error: %s\n", msg);
    std::fflush(stdout);
    std::abort();
}

template <typename T, T Val>
[[noreturn]] static inline void panic(Error<T, Val> e)
{
    panic_with_message(e.description());
}
```

You could put only the template into a header, along with a declaration of the function, and keep the function definition in a separate translation unit. That should keep the code bloat to a minimum:

```
// panic.hpp

#ifndef H_PANIC
#define H_PANIC

#include "error.hpp"  // for Error<T, Val>

[[noreturn]] void panic_with_message(char const * msg);

template <typename T, T Val>
[[noreturn]] static inline void panic(Error<T, Val> e)
{
    panic_with_message(e.description());
}

#endif
```

Comment: I admit to commonly making a `<void>` specialization of my templates and abusing it for this purpose :(

Comment: neither visual c++ 12.0 (2013) nor g++ 4.8.2 support `[[noreturn]]`. both compilers have pre-C++11 language extensions that do the same, respectively `__declspec( noreturn )` and `__attribute__((noreturn))`, IIRC. so in order to present examples that the users can try out, at this time I think it's better to capture the intended semantics by using a macro symbol, perhaps with a suggested implementation (or explanation).

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Are you sure that g++ 4.8.2 doesn't support `[[noreturn]]`? It [does compile](http://goo.gl/HZs6O8) at least in 4.8.1 and This suggests that generalized attributes were implemented in 4.8: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53528

Comment: @user2079303: thanks. now, since it compiles, i'm less sure. ;-)

Comment: @Kerrek SB: Hmm, that's somewhat in line with what I had in mind, although I would've hoped there was some neat template magic available. I am unfamiliar with `[[noreturn]]`, I guess it means the same thing as `_No_return` in C11?

Comment: @Skurmedel: I suppose so, I don't know C. You can leave out the attributes, they're just for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use extern template declarations. c++11 compilers and older visual studio versions support this (as a language extension.) Assuming you have a reasonably small number of Error instantiations, you can define an extern template declaration of panic for each one and place the actual function instantiation in a single translation unit. This ensures you only have one instantiation for each variant of panic.

panic.hpp

```
#ifndef PANIC_HPP
#define PANIC_HPP

template <typename TCode, TCode SuccessVal>
struct Error
{
    const char* description() { return "boom!"; }
};

template <typename TCode, TCode SuccessVal>
void panic(Error<TCode, SuccessVal> e);

//! So assume you have Error<ErrorCode, SuccessVal>
//! Place this in the header where the panic function prototype is declared.
//! You'll need one for each type or Error<T,Val> instantiation.
extern template void panic<int, 0>(Error<int, 0> e);
extern template void panic<int, 1>(Error<int, 1> e);
extern template void panic<int, 2>(Error<int, 2> e);

#endif//PANIC_HPP
```

panic.ipp

```
#ifndef PANIC_IPP
#define PANIC_IPP

#include "panic.hpp"
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

template <typename TCode, TCode SuccessVal>
inline void panic(Error<TCode, SuccessVal> e)
{
    printf("Unrecoverable error: %s scode: %d\n", e.description(), SuccessVal);
    std::abort();
}

#endif//PANIC_IPP
```

panic.cpp

```
#include "panic.ipp"

//! Declare the instantiation for each Error<T, Val> which you don't want duplicated.
template void panic<int, 0>(Error<int, 0> e);
template void panic<int, 1>(Error<int, 1> e);
template void panic<int, 2>(Error<int, 2> e);
```

main.cpp

```
#include "panic.hpp"

int main()
{
    panic(Error<int, 0>());
    panic(Error<int, 1>());//! These compile/link but aren't called due to abort.
    panic(Error<int, 2>());//! ...
    //panic(Error<int, 3>()); //! won't link due to unresolved symbol as not instantiated.
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note this can be combined with Kerrek's answer for an even better solution.